# Powershell method to silently uninstall office 2013

Tags: windows, powershell, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall Office 2013, both 32bit and 64bit versions across our network. I'v come up with a powershell script to try to uninstall these versions, but when it comes to the actual uninstall, I'm having no luck. I've tried many different methods.  Here are the errors are I receive for each one.

1)  This is the method that I would prefer but I receive the bootstrapper error.

> Start-Process -Filepath "\\server\share\office 2013\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/uninstall ProPlus","/config \\server\share\office\2013\proplus.ww\uninstallconfig.xml"

Here is what the xml file contains:
`<Configuration Product="ProPlus">
<Display Level="none" CompletionNotice="none" SuppressModal="yes" AcceptEula="yes" />
</Configuration>`

Note*:  When I don't include the "/config" argument, the uninstaller is launched but I need a **silent** uninstaller.

2)  I've tried the Get-Wmiobject win32_product search and then I use the uninstall() method from the class but it removes service packages and everything else related to Microsoft Office except Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013.

3)  I'v also tried the msexec.exe method with the GUID retrieved from the Get-wmiobject function.  It appears to run, but then it is cut off before it starts to uninstall and I get the blue loading circle right next to my cursor.  This displays on and off very quickly like it's trying to start up again.

I've been doing all of this through Powershell.  All of our installs have come from a networkshare.  I know that these processes are being run locally, once I have this part done I will start on the remote uninstallations, but for now I'd like to figure out why this local uninstallation isn't working.  I'd like to keep it through Powershell, thanks.  And yes, I'm running with elevated privileges.

Comment: Can you post the text of the bootstrapper error message?

Comment: "Microsoft Setup Bootstrapper has stopped working.  A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.  Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."  I don't find this error message quite helpful. :(

Comment: I see your code and doesn't have the double \\ in the parameter "-Filepath" and in the "/config"

    Start-Process -Filepath "\server\share\office 2013\setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/uninstall ProPlus","/config \server\share\office\2013\proplus.ww\uninstallconfig.xml"

Do you deleted for write here or that it's your code?

Comment: @RodolfoC.Méndez: if I understand correctly, backslashes don't need to be escaped in Powershell unless they are in a regex, which I don't think is the case here?

Comment: I have had similar issues, and ended up using the `OffScrub_O15msi.vbs` file and its command line methods shown here although this references 2010 the same commands apply to the O15.vbs version which you can search around online and find. If you have any troubles I can get you a copy of the file. [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2014/11/03/how-to-uninstall-office-2010-and-move-to-office-2013-click-to-run-or-volume-license/)

Comment: Sorry, the formatting for the submission of this problem messed with my spelling.  I corrected it above.

Comment: Thanks @ssaviers I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: @ssaviers It worked!  Thanks a bunch!